# Sending XML string in SOAP response

Tags: java, jax-ws

We have some web services built using the JAX WS framework. Those methods takes in Java objects as input and return Java objects which in turn are converted into XML by the framework.

Now I have a new use case where, I have the actual XML that needs to be returned to the client. How to put it in the SOAP response. Also the calling client should still be able to convert this reponse into Java objects without any impact.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply return a String object in your SOAP interface. As the return value, you can just return the XML as a String and the client can then use the XML in any way it wants.

If the client-side wants so have a Java object of the XML, it can of course use something like this to work with it:

```
String responseXml = WebServiceStuff.getXmlFromWebservice(); // this is your webservice
try
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    // factory.setNamespaceAware( true ); // if you need it
    // factory.setValidating( true ); // if you need it
    DocumentBuilder builder  = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse(responseXml);
    Node rootNode = document.getDocumentElement();
    // do something more with the XMLDocument
} 
catch (Exception e)
{
    // handle exception that happend while building the DOM
}
```

Comment: When I return the xml in a String variable in the SOAP response the xml string is being enclosed within <![CDATA[ xml string ]]>, whereas I want the string to not be enclosed in CDATA and put it right under the parent response tag.

Comment: Which library do you use? How about posting some code how you've implemented the service?